# Usar múltiples ventanas en JavaFX y regresar al original (Login)

Tags: javafx, ventana, scenebuilder

Estoy creando un login, consiste en introducir un usuario y contraseña, entonces al darle clic en validar, se me cierra el Login y me abre una nueva ventana (donde incluiré funciones que aun no implemento)...
pero está nueva ventana, tiene un boton de cerrado de sesión, como puedo hacer que al darle clic a ese botón, me regrese al Login?

Ya estuve buscando soluciones, pero todo me parece demasiado confuso, he visto que todo lo puedo cargar en el mismo Stage, solo cambiando la Scena, pero lo veo complejo, no entiendo como lo hace..., este es mi código.

**Clase main**

```
    package mainPack;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class mainC extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/GUIs/Login.fxml"));



        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    }

}
```

**LoginController**

```
package GUIs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */

    @FXML PasswordField txtPass;
    @FXML TextField txtUser;
    @FXML Label lblError;
    @FXML Label lblStatus;


    @FXML
    public void btnHandle(ActionEvent e) throws Exception{

        if(txtUser.getText().equals("Sistemas")  && txtPass.getText().equals("2019")){

            lblError.setOpacity(0);
            lblStatus.setText("Conectado.");

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/GUIs/Principal.fxml"));

            Scene escena = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(escena);
            stage.show();
//en esta linea, esconde el Stage del Login y carga el nuevo stage
            ( (Node) (e.getSource() ) ).getScene().getWindow().hide();

        }else{
            lblStatus.setText("Desconectado.");
            lblError.setOpacity(1);

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

**VentanaPrincipalController (despues del login)**

```
package GUIs;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author VAPESIN
 */
public class PrincipalController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */

    @FXML
    public void cerrarSesHandle(ActionEvent e){

    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

**Login.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="493.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="GUIs.LoginController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@login.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="49.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Usuario" />
      <Label layoutX="49.0" layoutY="148.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="Contraseña" />
      <Button layoutX="145.0" layoutY="252.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnHandle" text="Validar" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtUser" layoutX="145.0" layoutY="82.0" />
      <PasswordField fx:id="txtPass" layoutX="145.0" layoutY="159.0" />
      <Label fx:id="lblError" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="301.0" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="345.0" text="Usuario o Contraseña incorrecta." textFill="RED">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="lblStatus" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="330.0" text="Desconectado" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**VentanaPrincipal.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" fx:controller="GUIs.PrincipalController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@principal.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="167.0" layoutY="77.0" prefHeight="103.0" prefWidth="271.0" text="Bienvenido">
         <font>
            <Font size="53.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button layoutX="438.0" layoutY="345.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cerrarSesHandle" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Cerrar sesión" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image: Login]

Al darle click en cerrar, quisiera que me devolviera al Login.

[image: BienvenidoWindow]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hola mira puedes checar mi codigo en github sobre un sistema de mi escuela el cual implemente un login con su cerrar sesion y regresar eso de cerrar sesion y eso me acuerdo que tuve problemas porque se me pasmaba con los datos anteriores si quieres checa mi codigo https://github.com/WihoverEsal/ProyectoAsesorias esta en java FX 
a mira en mi codigo 
que tengo en esta parte en el github
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo este codigo que hize en mi boton para cerrar sesion y te regrese al login que aqui esta como puedes ver primero creo su setOnAction de ahi le agrego unos estilos a las letras y eso
esta parte es para el boton de cerrar sesion ya cuando quiero que se regrese 
a la ventana que quiero en el metodo que esta en la ultima parte ponemos nuestro constructor de la ventana hacia donde queremos que se regrese y bueno eso es todo espero y te sirva

```
    btCerrar.setOnAction(e -> {
        try {
            ButtonClicked(e);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    btCerrar.setStyle("-fx-font: 17 arial; -fx-base: #E91E63;");
    DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow();
    shadow.setColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color.web("#E91E63"));
    //Adding the shadow when the mouse cursor is on
    btCerrar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, 
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            btCerrar.setEffect(shadow);
            }
    });
    //Removing the shadow when the mouse cursor is off
    btCerrar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, 
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            btCerrar.setEffect(null);
        }
    });



    FlowPane pane1 = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL,15,15);
    FlowPane pane2 = new FlowPane(70,40);

     pane1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFC107;");
     pane2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFC107;");


    pane1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane2.getChildren().addAll(btCerrar/*,btBuscar*/);
    pane1.getChildren().addAll(materias,cbMaterias,profesores,lvProfesor,pane2);

    pane2.setPrefWidth(200);
    Scene escena = new Scene(pane1,300,300);



    stage.setScene(escena);
    stage.show();
}

public void ButtonClicked(ActionEvent e) throws Exception{

    if(e.getSource() == btCerrar){

        Login log = new Login();
        log.start(escenario);
    }
}
```

Comment: se te agradece la intención de ayuda pero responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, por favor lee [answer], edita esto y coloca las partes relevantes que ayudan a resolver el problema justo aquí

Comment: a ok si gracias por el comentario